# How do I get a the first value in a JSON array using Zapier?

Tags: javascript, json, zapier, riot-games-api

I am no programmer or coder by any means.  I'm just trying to use the Riot api to get some of my league of legends stats into zapier to use elsewhere.  I can get the json data just fine it's just it returns 10 data points for every stat.  I just want the first data point. This is the code I am using to get the data.

```
   fetch('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/game/by-summoner/61645956/recent?api_key=<myapikey>')
  .then(function(res) {
   return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

and it returns this array: (I had to cut off part of it to post this, it was too long.)

```
   {
   "summonerId":61645956,
  "games":[
  {
     "gameId":2305710206,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":200,
     "championId":89,
     "spell1":14,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":62,
     "createDate":1475123835392,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":26402335,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":122
        },
        {
           "summonerId":51664526,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":81
        },
        {
           "summonerId":38071418,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":103
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36515003,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":18
        },
        {
           "summonerId":48012068,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":48
        },
        {
           "summonerId":48064897,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":143
        },
        {
           "summonerId":45687834,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":36
        },
        {
           "summonerId":50239478,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":120
        },
        {
           "summonerId":30496298,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":1
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":13,
        "goldEarned":9165,
        "numDeaths":5,
        "minionsKilled":47,
        "championsKilled":3,
        "goldSpent":8725,
        "totalDamageDealt":26070,
        "totalDamageTaken":25068,
        "team":200,
        "win":false,
        "largestMultiKill":1,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":8335,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":10398,
        "physicalDamageTaken":15010,
        "magicDamageTaken":6577,
        "timePlayed":2033,
        "totalHeal":2665,
        "totalUnitsHealed":5,
        "assists":10,
        "item0":3401,
        "item1":3190,
        "item2":2049,
        "item3":1031,
        "item4":3111,
        "item5":3751,
        "item6":3364,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":3997,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":2654,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":7461,
        "trueDamageDealtPlayer":7336,
        "trueDamageDealtToChampions":810,
        "trueDamageTaken":3480,
        "wardKilled":2,
        "wardPlaced":22,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":125,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4,
        "visionWardsBought":1
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305656152,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":100,
     "championId":98,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":51,
     "createDate":1475121422227,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":44847062,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":222
        },
        {
           "summonerId":35024451,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":75
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36515003,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":81
        },
        {
           "summonerId":26655780,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":77
        },
        {
           "summonerId":22046951,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":161
        },
        {
           "summonerId":37418996,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":112
        },
        {
           "summonerId":37164256,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":121
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36386214,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":412
        },
        {
           "summonerId":70059201,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":122
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":11,
        "goldEarned":6345,
        "numDeaths":4,
        "minionsKilled":33,
        "championsKilled":1,
        "goldSpent":5750,
        "totalDamageDealt":17563,
        "totalDamageTaken":15701,
        "team":100,
        "win":false,
        "largestMultiKill":1,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":9109,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":1575,
        "physicalDamageTaken":6874,
        "magicDamageTaken":6798,
        "timePlayed":1519,
        "totalHeal":2132,
        "totalUnitsHealed":3,
        "assists":8,
        "item0":3401,
        "item1":3047,
        "item2":2049,
        "item3":3105,
        "item6":3341,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":1081,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":3906,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":4988,
        "trueDamageDealtPlayer":6878,
        "trueDamageTaken":2029,
        "wardKilled":2,
        "wardPlaced":11,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":112,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305599567,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":100,
     "championId":267,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":117,
     "createDate":1475119366312,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":36515003,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":236
        },
        {
           "summonerId":24318381,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":121
        },
        {
           "summonerId":58801818,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":48
        },
        {
           "summonerId":71530149,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":85
        },
        {
           "summonerId":429991,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":26
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36467378,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":110
        },
        {
           "summonerId":80651936,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":64
        },
        {
           "summonerId":21785827,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":115
        },
        {
           "summonerId":54995317,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":114
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":18,
        "goldEarned":14932,
        "numDeaths":6,
        "minionsKilled":32,
        "goldSpent":13325,
        "totalDamageDealt":42834,
        "totalDamageTaken":28128,
        "team":100,
        "win":true,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":17326,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":24972,
        "physicalDamageTaken":18318,
        "magicDamageTaken":9570,
        "timePlayed":2621,
        "totalHeal":25516,
        "totalUnitsHealed":5,
        "assists":25,
        "item0":3092,
        "item1":3190,
        "item2":2045,
        "item3":3117,
        "item4":3504,
        "item5":3050,
        "item6":3364,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":10608,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":1632,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":12241,
        "trueDamageDealtPlayer":535,
        "trueDamageTaken":240,
        "wardKilled":3,
        "wardPlaced":26,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":269,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4,
        "totalDamageDealtToBuildings":5540,
        "visionWardsBought":3
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305593891,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":200,
     "championId":26,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":96,
     "createDate":1475116337677,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":59240130,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":90
        },
        {
           "summonerId":37737286,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":5
        },
        {
           "summonerId":48134049,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":25
        },
        {
           "summonerId":52001343,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":104
        },
        {
           "summonerId":23929258,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":67
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36515003,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":236
        },
        {
           "summonerId":71539264,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":133
        },
        {
           "summonerId":73074002,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":103
        },
        {
           "summonerId":57259369,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":23
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":15,
        "goldEarned":10822,
        "numDeaths":5,
        "turretsKilled":2,
        "minionsKilled":46,
        "championsKilled":1,
        "goldSpent":9800,
        "totalDamageDealt":60871,
        "totalDamageTaken":14379,
        "team":200,
        "win":true,
        "largestMultiKill":1,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":7532,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":53339,
        "physicalDamageTaken":7061,
        "magicDamageTaken":6431,
        "timePlayed":2090,
        "totalHeal":8278,
        "totalUnitsHealed":5,
        "assists":14,
        "item0":3092,
        "item1":3158,
        "item2":2049,
        "item3":3512,
        "item4":3165,
        "item6":3364,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":8992,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":1933,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":10925,
        "trueDamageTaken":886,
        "wardKilled":1,
        "wardPlaced":11,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":201,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4,
        "totalDamageDealtToBuildings":1733,
        "visionWardsBought":2
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305548000,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":100,
     "championId":26,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":76,
     "createDate":1475113731759,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":50558512,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":81
        },
        {
           "summonerId":29276199,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":51
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36654393,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":240
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36515003,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":223
        },
        {
           "summonerId":76800634,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":11
        },
        {
           "summonerId":50445070,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":222
        },
        {
           "summonerId":52201449,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":4
        },
        {
           "summonerId":11625,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":106
        },
        {
           "summonerId":30564904,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":89
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":13,
        "goldEarned":8724,
        "numDeaths":2,
        "turretsKilled":1,
        "minionsKilled":38,
        "championsKilled":1,
        "goldSpent":6360,
        "totalDamageDealt":52177,
        "totalDamageTaken":7009,
        "team":100,
        "win":true,
        "neutralMinionsKilled":6,
        "largestMultiKill":1,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":8451,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":43726,
        "physicalDamageTaken":5381,
        "magicDamageTaken":1470,
        "timePlayed":1519,
        "totalHeal":1931,
        "totalUnitsHealed":1,
        "assists":7,
        "item0":3092,
        "item1":3158,
        "item2":2049,
        "item3":3108,
        "item4":3802,
        "item5":1052,
        "item6":3364,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":5029,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":974,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":6004,
        "trueDamageTaken":157,
        "wardPlaced":14,
        "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":3,
        "neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle":3,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":214,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4,
        "totalDamageDealtToBuildings":5840,
        "visionWardsBought":1
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305542650,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":200,
     "championId":25,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":82,
     "createDate":1475111487614,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":49111930,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":17
        },
        {
           "summonerId":29149315,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":107
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36515003,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":104
        },
        {
           "summonerId":69370945,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":115
        },
        {
           "summonerId":25972662,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":53
        },
        {
           "summonerId":73929624,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":2
        },
        {
           "summonerId":36783010,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":236
        },
        {
           "summonerId":35386736,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":61
        },
        {
           "summonerId":29070094,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":5
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":14,
        "goldEarned":10650,
        "numDeaths":1,
        "barracksKilled":1,
        "turretsKilled":2,
        "minionsKilled":34,
        "championsKilled":2,
        "goldSpent":8650,
        "totalDamageDealt":51368,
        "totalDamageTaken":10392,
        "killingSprees":1,
        "largestKillingSpree":2,
        "team":200,
        "win":true,
        "neutralMinionsKilled":1,
        "largestMultiKill":1,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":10713,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":40654,
        "physicalDamageTaken":3723,
        "magicDamageTaken":6620,
        "timePlayed":1698,
        "totalHeal":1437,
        "totalUnitsHealed":1,
        "assists":16,
        "item0":3092,
        "item1":2031,
        "item2":2049,
        "item3":3157,
        "item4":3020,
        "item5":3105,
        "item6":3364,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":10747,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":1355,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":12103,
        "trueDamageTaken":48,
        "wardKilled":3,
        "wardPlaced":18,
        "neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle":1,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":151,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4,
        "bountyLevel":2,
        "totalDamageDealtToBuildings":5974
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305309550,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":200,
     "championId":26,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":230,
     "createDate":1475109305903,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":58049719,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":412
        },
        {
           "summonerId":57761286,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":18
        },
        {
           "summonerId":60661724,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":51
        },
        {
           "summonerId":69852470,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":245
        },
        {
           "summonerId":35240348,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":41
        },
        {
           "summonerId":64891806,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":99
        },
        {
           "summonerId":19810065,
           "teamId":200,
           "championId":154
        },
        {
           "summonerId":72219120,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":64
        },
        {
           "summonerId":29290889,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":19
        }
     ],
     "stats":{
        "level":13,
        "goldEarned":9891,
        "numDeaths":2,
        "minionsKilled":46,
        "championsKilled":2,
        "goldSpent":8925,
        "totalDamageDealt":54060,
        "totalDamageTaken":8547,
        "team":200,
        "win":true,
        "neutralMinionsKilled":7,
        "largestMultiKill":1,
        "physicalDamageDealtPlayer":5671,
        "magicDamageDealtPlayer":48342,
        "physicalDamageTaken":3440,
        "magicDamageTaken":5107,
        "timePlayed":1676,
        "totalHeal":4528,
        "totalUnitsHealed":2,
        "assists":17,
        "item0":3092,
        "item1":3158,
        "item2":2049,
        "item3":3165,
        "item4":3105,
        "item5":1028,
        "item6":3364,
        "magicDamageDealtToChampions":8314,
        "physicalDamageDealtToChampions":1984,
        "totalDamageDealtToChampions":10299,
        "trueDamageDealtPlayer":45,
        "wardKilled":1,
        "wardPlaced":15,
        "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":7,
        "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":256,
        "playerRole":2,
        "playerPosition":4,
        "totalDamageDealtToBuildings":2077,
        "visionWardsBought":1
     }
  },
  {
     "gameId":2305304640,
     "invalid":false,
     "gameMode":"CLASSIC",
     "gameType":"MATCHED_GAME",
     "subType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
     "mapId":11,
     "teamId":100,
     "championId":89,
     "spell1":3,
     "spell2":4,
     "level":30,
     "ipEarned":64,
     "createDate":1475107215636,
     "fellowPlayers":[
        {
           "summonerId":34093650,
           "teamId":100,
           "championId":75
        },
```

But in zapier it is formatted as: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA876.jpg

What can I add to this code or run a different action code to get the first values for each of these fields?  If that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: `Obj.games.length = EXPECTED_GAMES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the full json value like `callback(null, json)`, try using the property `games` and the array indexing `[0]` to get a subset of the data like `callback(null, json.games[0])`.

Note, if you want to trigger on new games (IE: after each game is played, start a workflow), return the array and Zapier will watch for new games (though you may need to specify a specific property to be the `id`, since it doesn't likely understand that `gameId` is the identifier). IE: like this `callback(null, json.games)`.

Comment: Awesome that worked Bryan! 
[Pic](http://imgur.com/L9vwz7I)

Any way you could give me a bit more understanding on Zapier triggering when a new game? 

But I'm very happy with this working as a non programmer!